# How to parallelize reading lines from an input file when lines get independently processed?

Tags: c++, openmp, parallel-processing

I just started off with OpenMP using C++. My serial code in C++ looks something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    string line;
    std::ifstream inputfile(argv[1]);

    if(inputfile.is_open()) {
        while(getline(inputfile, line)) {
            // Line gets processed and written into an output file
        }
    }
}
```

Because each line is pretty much independently processed, I was attempting to use OpenMP to parallelize this because the input file is in the order of gigabytes. So I'm guessing that first I need to get the number of lines in the input file and then parallelize the code this way. Can someone please help me out here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef _OPENMP
#include <omp.h>
#endif

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    string line;
    std::ifstream inputfile(argv[1]);

    if(inputfile.is_open()) {
        //Calculate number of lines in file?
        //Set an output filename and open an ofstream
        #pragma omp parallel num_threads(8)
        {
            #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic, 1000)
            for(int i = 0; i < lines_in_file; i++) {
                 //What do I do here? I cannot just read any line because it requires random access
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

**Important Things**

1. Each line is independently processed
2. Order of the results don't matter

Comment: You say each line is independent, but what about the order of the results?

Comment: @aneccodeal: That's independent too because I will be inserting this data into a database in the end.

Comment: Assuming all the lines are (roughly) the same length, you don't need to count the number of lines (that's expensive; you have to read the whole file!)  You can compute the size of the file (seek to the end and see where the pointer is at), divide it into eight chunks by the number of bytes, then seek each chunk pointer (other than the initial one) forward until it reaches a new line.

Comment: [Also, your file reading code (testing `eof()`) is wrong.](http://punchlet.wordpress.com/2009/12/01/hello-world/)

Comment: ...for example, if you're counting the number of times a particular string appears in the file then order doesn't matter, but if you're filtering out some string from the file and need to reassemble the input in order then order is important.

Comment: @James: Thanks for the input. I changed my file reading. Appreciate it.

Comment: There is a risk of making things (much!) *worse* this way. It depends on the interaction of the read caching and seeking. At least with storage media that have heads that have to seek. I assume it is less likely with solid state storage devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a direct OpenMP answer - but what you are probably looking for is [Map/Reduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) approach. Take a look at [Hadoop](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/C%2B%2BWordCount) - it's done in Java, but there's some C++ API at least.

In general, you want to process this amount of data on different machines, not in multiple threads in the same process (virtual address space limitations, lack of physical memory, swapping, etc.) Also the kernel will have to bring the disk file in sequentially anyway (which you want - otherwise the hard-drive will just have to do extra seeks for each of your threads).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What you said makes perfect sense now.